# Simple Cypher Program Not Resetting Correctly

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm learning programming and c++ as my first language for fun. I'm trying to create a simple program that encrypts and decrypts input so I can practice with strings.

Everything works okay, but somehow I am ending up with old inputs popping up when i run the program again for a second time.

For example if I input "greg" , then decrypt it, then enter greg again, I get two "greg"(encrypted)- so it's not resetting correctly, it will keep adding new words on without resetting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string alphabet{"a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 "
                  "5 6 7 8 9 0"};
  string key{"m h i p g f b t x u r l w a j e q k z d y v o c n s 9 5 0 7 8 2 "
             "3 4 1 6"};
  string word{};
  string secretword{};
  string decryptedword{};
  int selection{};
  // int newpos {};
  int position{};
  //int keypos{};

  do {
    cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Select an Option: " << endl;
    cout << "1: Encrypt" << endl;
    cout << "2: Decrypt" << endl;
    cout << "3: Quit" << endl;

    cin >> selection;

    if (selection == 1) {
      cout << "Enter a Word to Encrypt:";
      cin.sync();
      getline(cin, word);

      for (auto i : word) {
        if (isupper(i)) {
          cout << "Please use lower case only" << endl;
          break;
        }

        position = alphabet.find(i);
        secretword += key.at(position);
      }
      cout << "Encrypted Word: " << secretword << endl;
      secretword = "";
    }

    if (selection == 2) {
      cout << "Enter a Word to Decrypt: ";
      cin.sync();
      getline(cin, secretword);

      for (auto i : secretword) {
        if (isupper(i)) {
          cout << "Please use lower case only" << endl;
          break;
        }
        position = key.find(i);
        decryptedword += alphabet.at(position);
      }

      cout << "Decrypted Word: " << decryptedword << endl;
      decryptedword = "";
    }
  } while (selection != 3);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The program uses `secretword` for both the output of encryption and the the input of decryption and never clears it. Ooops.

Rather than clearing variables, reduce their scope so that they do not need to be cleared and cannot conflict. Eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string alphabet { "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 1 2 3 4 "
                      "5 6 7 8 9 0" };
    string key { "m h i p g f b t x u r l w a j e q k z d y v o c n s 9 5 0 7 8 2 "
                 "3 4 1 6" };
    //int keypos{};

    int selection;
    do
    {
        cout << "-------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "Select an Option: " << endl;
        cout << "1: Encrypt" << endl;
        cout << "2: Decrypt" << endl;
        cout << "3: Quit" << endl;

        cin >> selection;

        if (selection == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter a Word to Encrypt:";
            cin.sync();
            string word;
            string secretword;
            getline(cin, word);

            for (auto i : word)
            {
                if (isupper(i))
                {
                    cout << "Please use lower case only" << endl;
                    break;
                }

                auto position = alphabet.find(i);
                secretword += key.at(position);
            }
            cout << "Encrypted Word: " << secretword << endl;
            secretword = "";
        }

        if (selection == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter a Word to Decrypt: ";
            cin.sync();
            string secretword;
            string decryptedword;
            getline(cin, secretword);

            for (auto i : secretword)
            {
                if (isupper(i))
                {
                    cout << "Please use lower case only" << endl;
                    break;
                }
                auto position = key.find(i);
                decryptedword += alphabet.at(position);
            }

            cout << "Decrypted Word: " << decryptedword << endl;
            decryptedword = "";
        }
    } while (selection != 3);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this isn't always the right answer, there are performance implications, but the less manual book-keeping you have to do, the better. Only complicate the code when you can't meet a performance target and only complicate the code that is demonstrated by profiling to be a significant problem.